# PGC-1β Sod2 limiters/blockers

Tags: human-biology, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, mitochondria

I'd like to block a percentage of PGC-1β or Sod2 expression. According to the following paper's figure beta-blockers inhibit some expression of PGC-1α. Are there any medicines/chemicals which safely and temporarily block 50%-60% expression of PGC-1β or Sod2 in fully developed mice or humans? 
Thank you

http://jap.physiology.org/content/107/1/8.full

Fig. 1.
Interactions of β-blockers and mitochondrial biogenesis. Aerobic exercise activates β2-adrenergic receptors (β-AR) on skeletal muscle and induces peroxisome proliferator-activated receptor-γ coactivator-1α (PGC-1α) transcription, a regulator of mitochondrial biogenesis. Selective and nonselective β-blockers can blunt β2-AR signaling, which restricts the expected PGC-1α response following exercise and can impair adaptations to mitochondria and aerobic capacity. V̇O2max, maximum oxygen consumption.

Comment: Perhaps there is a transgenic mouse model available that uses a conditional knock-down approach?

Comment: @leonardo there is a transgenic mouse and there is a vector based method of depleting Sod2 and PGC-1β but it wont help me because the transition needs to be reversible

Comment: right, that's why I qualified the "conditional" knock-down. Not knowing these lines, vector based sounds like it could be reversible (eg, stop delivering the vector). The transgenic mouse might be a knock-out rather than a knock-down/conditional knock-out.

Comment: @leonardo yeah that is right the only thing is viral vectors cause leukemia in the long run; cell penetrating peptides are safe and fda aproved but they can only carry one cargo at a time as best i know

Comment: Maybe you can design a new transgenic model then. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dexamethasone can be used to regulate PGC-1β 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20647557